# Optimizing a do while loop/for loop in C

Tags: c, for-loop, optimization, do-while

I was doing an exercise from  LeetCode in which consisted in deleting any adjacent elements from a string, until there are only unique characters adjacent to each other. With some help I could make a code that can solve most testcases, but the string length can be up to 10^5, and in a testcase it exceeds the time limit, so I'm in need in some tips on how can I optimize it.

**My code:**

```
char res[100000];  //up to 10^5

char * removeDuplicates(char * s){
    //int that verifies if any char from the string can be deleted
    int ver = 0;

   //do while loop that reiterates to eliminate the duplicates
    do {
    int lenght = strlen(s);
    int j = 0;
    ver = 0;

    //for loop that if there are duplicates adds one to ver and deletes the duplicate
    for (int i = 0; i < lenght ; i++){
        if (s[i] == s[i + 1]){
            i++;
            j--;
            ver++;
        }
        else {
            res[j] = s[i];
        }
        j++;
    }
    //copying the res string into the s to redo the loop if necessary
    strcpy(s,res);
    //clar the res string
    memset(res, '\0', sizeof res);
    } while (ver > 0);
    return s;
}
```

The code can't pass a speed test that has a string that has around the limit (10^5) length, I won't put it here because it's a really big text, but if you want to check it, it is the 104 testcase from the [LeetCode Daily Problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/remove-all-adjacent-duplicates-in-string/)

Comment: Repeated calls to `strlen` on long strings in a loop is very inefficient. Try to optimize this.

Comment: You don't need that `memset` call. You have the index where the last character was added to `res`, so you can just add the null-terminator at the next index.

Comment: Your algorithm is inefficient. Imagine you do not have to remove something in the first 1000 characters and then remove the 1001st and 1002nd character, why do you start from the beginning, where nothing changed? Start at 1000, which can match the new 1001st character.

Comment: Also, since you know the length of the string in `res`, you can use it as the length of `s` in the next iteration so don't need `strlen` inside the loop either.

Comment: And you can actually do this with only a single loop passing over the characters in the input string, just copying unique characters to the destination string and skipping over the duplicates, in an O(n) solution.

Comment: If you want help with optimizing working code, then https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ is better suited. Make sure to include the complete code and all includes.

Comment: I did some of the suggestions that you guys said, I removed the strlen from the loop, only calling it once at the beginning of the code and changed the memset to a for loop to only change the characters that are already modified but the code still can't pass the test. I wasn't able to implement the changes that mch said and the single loop that the programmed dude suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it was me doing something like that, I would basically do it like a simple naive string copy, but keep track of the last character copied and if the next character to copy is the same as the last then skip it.

Perhaps something like this:

```
char result[1000];  // Assumes no input string will be longer than this

unsigned source_index;  // Index into the source string
unsigned dest_index;    // Index into the destination (result) string

// Always copy the first character
result[0] = source_string[0];

// Start with 1 for source index, since we already copies the first character
for (source_index = 1, dest_index = 0; source_string[source_index] != '\0'; ++source_index)
{
    if (source_string[source_index] != result[dest_index])
    {
        // Next character is not equal to last character copied
        // That means we can copy this character
        result[++dest_index] = source_string[source_index];
    }

    // Else: Current source character was equal to last copied character
}

// Terminate the destination string
result[dest_index + 1] = '\0';
```